# uitextfield with creditcard number

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` to enter a credit card number.

When a user types the creditcard number it should be displayed as X for the first 12 digits and the last 4 digits should display the orginal value.

```
Eg:XXXX XXXX XXXX 4159
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: So? show us what you tried till now. Also, visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hope the below links help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244313/card-number-first-12-digits-should-be-secure-entry-and-remaining-4-digits-as-nor

Comment: Normally, the whole number is shown while the user enters the number, and the masked version is only shown when confirming stored details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244313/card-number-first-12-digits-should-be-secure-entry-and-remaining-4-digits-as-nor?lq=1  will help you some how

Comment: Why can't I see my own credit card number while I'm editing the field. What happens if I mistype?